# How to integrate Flowplayer in ExtJS 4.1

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, flowplayer

I am trying to integrate Flowplayer in ExtJS by using `Ext.flash.Component`. While doing  this, i am getting following error -

```
 ReferenceError: swfobject is not defined
new swfobject.embedSWF(
```

Here is my code -

```
var win = Ext.widget('window', {
    title: "Flowplayer Integration",
    layout: 'fit',
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    x: 20,
    y: 20,
    resizable: true,
    items: {
        xtype: 'flash',
        url: 'flowplayer-3.2.16.swf'
    }
});
win.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

This component requires the third-party SWFObject library version 2.2 or above. It is not included within the ExtJS distribution, so you will have to include it into your page manually in order to use this component.

1. Download swfobject.js from http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/
2. Require it, 
   like this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/swfobject.js"></script>` 
   or like this: `Ext.require( '/js/swfobject.js' )`

Comment: I have already added `flowplayer-3.2.12.min.js`. So do i have to add `swfobject.js`?

Comment: Yes, Ext.flash.Component require it